# JAVA GSON date converter : How to get midnight as 00:00 AM instead of 12:00 AM

Tags: java, json, date, gson

I use GSON to get a Json with different data. Everything works fine but when the user type 00:30:00 AM as half past midnight, it is converted as 12:30:00 AM. I d like to have it as 00:30:00 AM.
Is there a way to do without changing anything else in date conversion ?

Comment: Is GSON giving you the time as a string in that format? (Where I learnt the AM/PM system, 12:30 AM is correct for half past midnight, BTW.)

Comment: Yes it s a String format. and I d need all the hours between midnight and 1 am to be  changed into 00:{the right minute}:00

Answer (score 1):

I would have preferred to persuade GSON to give me the desired format, but sorry, I don’t know GSON so cannot tell you whether that’s possible. However, if it isn’t, reformatting the string you get isn’t difficult when you know how:

```
    DateTimeFormatter gsonTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a");
    DateTimeFormatter desiredTineFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("KK:mm:ss a");
    String timeStringFromGson = "12:30:00 AM";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeStringFromGson, gsonTimeFormatter);
    String formattedTime = time.format(desiredTineFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 00:30:00 AM

The format pattern letters `hh` (lowercase) and `KK` (uppercase) both mean hour within AM or PM, but the former goes from 01 through 12, the latter from 00 through 11, so gives you the desired hour, also in case the hour from GSON happened to be 12.

Answer (score 0):

Set your date format when creating gson object from Gson builder.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").create();
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. or may I didnt get your answer but I dont see how setDateFormat(HH:mm) would get me a 00:30:00 AM instead of a 12:30:00 AM ?

Comment: @Jean your question is begging for bad answers, since you didn't post any code allowing us to understand, reproduce and fix the problem. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Added `ss` for seconds. Just wonder why you need AM while the hour is in 00-23.

Comment: The original code is not mine. That s why I want to touch the Json generated as less as possible. The Json never sends 12-24 hours. But the app using this Json generates 00-24 hours.

Comment: How would this answer treat, say, `01:15:00 PM`?

Comment: 01:15:00 PM in a json would be considered as 13.15 on the app  (I cant do anything about the app code )